# node.js http.get xml is blank

Tags: xml, node.js

http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/softwaredevelopers/rates/exrates-monthly-0616.xml

I'm trying to get the xml from the above hrmc website url into node.js (I intend to parse it into json later).

As the hrmc states

> You should use these exchanges rates if you have to convert any foreign currency to sterling for customs and VAT purposes.

**please no answers on alternate places I can find exchange rates**

```
function hrmc(cb){
    var m=new Date().getMonth()+1;
    if(m<10){m='0'+m;}
    var y=((new Date().getFullYear()+'').substr(2));
    var req=require('http').get({host:'www.hmrc.gov.uk',path:'/softwaredevelopers/rates/exrates-monthly-'+m+y+'.xml'},function(res){
        var xml='';
        res.on('error',function(e){console.dir(['res error',e]);});
        res.on('data',function(chunk){xml+=chunk;});
        res.on('end',function(){
            //
            console.log(xml);// '' <--empty?
            //cb(xml);
            });});
    req.on('error',function(e){console.dir(['req error',e]);});}
```

**The problem is that I get an empty string and no errors**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
var http = require('http');    

http.get('http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/softwaredevelopers/rates/exrates-monthly-0616.xml', (response) => {

    var xml = '';

    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        xml += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log(xml); //not empty!
    })

}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.log('error: ' + e.message);
});
```

Comment: don't understand why that works and mine doesn't. but thanks!